# How do I fix an installation error message saying: executing grub-install /dev/sda3 failed?

Tags: 11.04, installation, partitioning, ubuntu-netbook

When installing the newest Ubuntu 11.04 on an Acer Aspire 1 netbook, the installer said

> no bootable programs found

or something to that effect, so I made another partition of 5 gigs and attempted to install there.  I currently have Wary Puppy installed on the 1st partition.  Went through the install, then the error message said:

```
executing grub-install /dev/sda3 failed
this is a fatal error
file report at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ source/ubiquity/+ filebug
include details + bug report + attach these files
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/partman:
```

Neither of these files are in the partition's `/var/log/` folders.

Comment: run this: sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda3